# Ticket command giving errors discord js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i need help with this for someone reason when i type !ticket it gives me a error the code and the error i tried what i could i couldent get it to work so i came here to ask please let me know if you could help. its probably a really simple issue and im dumb to realize it. i also cant get the emojis to work if you can help with that as well that would be nice

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ticket',
    usage: '%ticket <reason>',
    description: 'makes a ticket',

    async execute(client, message, args, cmd, discord) {
        const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.user.tag}`);
        channel.setParent('855596395783127081');

        channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGE: false,
            VEIW_CHANNEL: false
        })
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.auther, {
            SEND_MESSAGE: true,
            VEIW_CHANNEL: true
        })

        const reactionMessage = await channel.send(`Thank you for contacting support! A staff member will be with you as soon as possible`);

        try {

            await reactionMessage.react(":lock:");
            await reactionMessage.react(":no_entry:");
        } catch (err) {
            channel.send(`Error Sending Emojis`);
            throw err;
        }

        const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector((reaction, user) =>
            message.guild.member.cache.find((member) => member.id === userid).hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR'), { dispose: true }
        );

        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case ":lock:":
                    channel.updateOverwrite(message.auther, { SEND_MESSAGE: false });
                    break;
                case ":no_entry:":
                    channel.send('Deleteing ticket in 5 seconds');
                    setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
                    break;
            }
        });

        message.channel.send(`We will be right withyou! ${channel}`).then((msg) => {
            setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000)
            setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 7000)
        })
    }
}
```

Heres the error

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:19284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\ticket.js:10:85)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\events\guild\message.js:10:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19284) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of 
an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19284) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that 
are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: ok got part of it working just needa get the emojis working its saying Unknown emojis

Answer (score 0):

In `Message` Object there is no properties that called `.user` it should be `.author` which is return `User` Object , docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author)

So the right code will be

```js
        const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`);
```